# How do you check if a JavaScript Object is a new DOM Element?

Tags: javascript, html, qunit, google-blockly

I have a function

```
mutationToDom: function() {
    var container = document.createElement( 'mutation' );

    container.setAttribute( 'string', 'test' );

    return container;
}
```

The container is `<mutation string="test"></mutation>`

How can I check it after I call this function in my Unit test?

```
QUnit.test( 'check function mutationToDom', function( assert ) {
    var container = testBlock.mutationToDom();
    assert.ok( container === ???, 'mutation is created with correct value' );
});
```

---

Try #1

I tried with `XMLSerializer()` to convert the XML to string

`var containerString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(container);`

but, the `containerString` is

`"<mutation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" string="test"></mutation>"`

instead of `"<mutation string="test"></mutation>"`

Comment: `container instanceof HTMLElement`

Comment: @JaromandaX the <mutation> is not a standard HTMLElement, so the result of this comparison is false

Comment: `container instanceof HTMLUnknownElement`

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried `HTMLUnknownElement` already, and result is false too. But, I dont want to check by this way, bcz I do not know the container is exact `<mutation string="test"></mutation>`

Comment: check for one or the other - though, if unknown doesn't work ... what is the result of `Object.prototype.toString.call(container)`

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(container)` --> `"[object HTMLUnknownElement]" `

Comment: `container.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "MUTATION" && container.classList.contains("test")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about checking for the `outerHTML`?

```js
var testBlock = {
  mutationToDom: function() {
    var container = document.createElement('mutation');
    container.setAttribute('string', 'test');
    return container;
  }
};

QUnit.test( 'check function mutationToDom', function( assert ) {
    var container = testBlock.mutationToDom();
    assert.ok( container.outerHTML === '<mutation string="test"></mutation>', 'mutation is created with correct value' );
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.6.0.css">
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.6.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question in the title, try `testObject instanceof Element` or `...HTMLElement`? This might be a precondition of checking the `.outerHTML`, as suggested by 31piy.